# Formal languages generator?

Tags: c#, .net, grammar, formal-languages

I'm wondering if there exists a library (preferably in .NET) for generating outputs based on formal grammars.

I'm talking about this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Formal_grammars

So you give it the grammar as in:

(Non-terminal symbols, Terminal symbols, Production rules, Start symbol)

so:

```
Grammar = ({E,A,B}, {(,),a,+,*}, P, E);
Where
P = {
    E -> A,
    E -> E + A,
    A -> B,
    A -> A * B,
    B -> a,
    B -> (E)
};
```

And then the library would produce example random outputs of that grammar like:

```
a * a + a
a + (a + a)
a * a * a
```

What I'm going to do after either creating or finding a library like this is to then change the way it produces the output to make it more biased to produce certain examples more than others, so in the previous example I can make it more biased to produce more expressions with addition in them rather than multiplication.

So basically assign weights to production rules to make some of them more likely to get applied when there is more than one valid.

So my main question is, is there a library out there that can do the first step which is producing random outputs based on a formal grammar like my example?

**Update**

Thinking about this problem again, I have a few more notes:

- One of the problems here is to know when to stop applying production rules. Either make sure that the grammar does stop at some point or devise a way in the algorithm/code that makes it less likely to keep expanding the expression further on.
- I realise now that this might be too theoretical and there is probably a more practical way. I mean, there have to be some tools out there that essentially do this same thing but maybe just use a different syntax or approach that is more specific to certain problems or maybe something more flexible.

Comment: Won't that take like an hour, maybe two, to write yourself?

Comment: @Dukeling.. Have you seen what this may involve?

Comment: @NewAmbition Maybe I'm just missing some significant detail or two, but it seems like it would just involve a somewhat simple recursive function, or maybe a stack will be better. The only possible issue I see might be getting a nice random distribution.

Comment: claculating the finite set of production rules, nonterminal symbols,  terminal symbols - checking for a start symbol.. `that may be constructed by applying production rules to another sequence of symbols which initially contains just the start symbol.`.. Which is in the first 1/10 of the Wiki post... yeah.. and in development, even a 'slight detail' may take a day or two to fix.

Comment: @NewAmbition You do realize the goal here is just to produce random outputs, not to check if some string is in the language (which would be somewhat more difficult, or, at least, slower)? Ok, maybe doing it in an hour or two would require extensive programming experience, but it still doesn't seem like a big task.

Comment: @Dukeling good point - but the use (such as the reference to the article) to the system would be to still use what it provides to the fullest

Comment: A basic implementation indeed can be done in one hour: http://pastebin.com/xZ6GWdfS It's neither nice nor performance oriented, but it already solves one important problem: Make sure the result has a sane length: `weightMultiplier`. The longer the algorithm runs, the more the weight of the weighted production rules increase. To actually use this to keep the result short, the paths to the terminal symbols need to have more weight than the remaining paths. I don't know, but it might show that I have no formal CS education.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks for that, it's simple but it's still useful to check.